# Is it fine to await for one Task but not for other?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a following service method,

```
public async Task<IList<ProductsImage>> InsertAsync(BaseProduct product, Dictionary<string, Stream> images)
{
    try
    {
        if (images.Count > 0)
        {
            await _imageService.SaveAllAsync(images);
        }
        return await _repository.InsertAsync(product);
    }
    catch // Delete the files if there is an error from db
    {
        if (images.Count > 0)
        {
            var paths = images.Select(i => i.Key).ToList();
            _imageService.DeleteAllAsync(paths);                        
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to await at `_imageService.DeleteAllAsync` because it takes some time to finish, so that I can transfer my execution without waiting. Is there any danger of not using await in `_imageService.DeleteAllAsync`

Comment: Yes... if something goes wrong, where do the errors go?

Comment: If your process exits during the deletion (ASP.NET worker processes do all the time) the work is lost.

Comment: Is the question about ASP.NET? If so, this has surfaced many times on SO, check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html. The other (minor) problem is that you would not be able to `await` inside `catch` (not until the next version of C#).

Comment: spender and usr, means I need another try/catch block? can I use `queuebackgroundworkitem` here, stackoverflow.com/questions/23978511/difference-between-hostingenvironment-queuebackgroundworkitem-and-hostingenviron

Comment: Unawaited task aside this is paving way for data corruption down the track. If the end target of `InsertAsync` is the database, why not utilise a database transaction? Or, at the very least, perform the insert such that it leaves the objects in a "pending" state where they are not yet considered valid and usable according to your business rules, and run an atomic update to mark them as "good to go" at the very end?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, Catch is possible in unknown case? Network/No-Connection

Comment: @user960567, not sure I understand your "unknown case", but if `InsertAsync` is likely to face network connectivity issues, `DeleteAllAsync` is likely to be subject to the very same issues. Even in the case when `DeleteAllAsync` successfully rolls back changes committed by the partial add, there is still a window of time where your data store will contain garbage (partially inserted data). If `DeleteAllAsync` fails, that garbage becomes permanent. This whole problem just isn't something you can solve with a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to send this message to a message queue so it can be processed asynchronously (without await) by an outside process. This way it will also guarantee that DeleteAllAsync will get called or retried if it fails.

Here is my [shameless plug](http://blog.maskalik.com/message-queue/2014/08/11/amazon-sqs-message-processor/) for the article I wrote on this subject.